# Working powershell script won't run as scheduled task (Windows IOT - RPI 3)

Tags: powershell, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot

We want to make our app to upgrade automatically. Since Windows IOT doesn't have Windows Store we have to do manually.

Here is our solution. Our app checks every 7 days if there is new version on our web server. If it is, app download it in folder \LocalState\Install.

Next part is powershell script that checks every hour if there is files in that folder. If it is she install it.

Problem is that we cannot start script as scheduled task and also we cannot run it with powershell -File  (we tried all the options with UnRestricted, Bypass and RemoteSigned, we also signed it).

Script is ok and does the work when we start it from command line.

Is there any solution? Please help :)

```
    $items = Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\Packages\"

foreach ($item in $items)
{
      # if the item is a directory, then process it.
      if ($item.Attributes -eq "Directory")
      {
            if ($item.name -Match "<app name>") {           
                "Backuping ini files..."
                $AppPath = "c:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\Packages\" + $item + "\LocalState"
                $AppName = $item
                cp "$AppPath\*.ini" "C:\Data\Users\Administrator\Temp"

                $path1 = "c:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\Packages\" + $item.name + "\LocalState\Install\"
                $path = Get-ChildItem -Path $path1          
                $dependencies1 = $path1 + "Dependencies\ARM\"
                $dependencies = Get-ChildItem -Path $dependencies1              
                "Dependencies..."
                foreach ($dependency in $dependencies)
                {
                      if ($dependency.Attributes -ne "Directory")
                      {
                            "***** Installing: " + $dependency
                            Add-AppxPackage -ForceApplicationShutdown $dependencies1$dependency                   }
                }

                "APP update..."
                foreach ($p in $path)
                {
                      # if the item is NOT a directory, then process it.
                      if ($p.Attributes -ne "Directory")
                      {
                        if ($p.name -Match "appxbundle") {
                            "***** Installing: " + $p
                            Add-AppxPackage -ForceApplicationShutdown $path1$p                  
                        }   
                      }
                }       

                "Removing install files..."
                rm $path1\* -Recurse

                "Restoring ini files..."
                cp "C:\Data\Users\Administrator\Temp\*.ini" "$AppPath\"

                "Setting APP as default app"
                IotStartup add headed $AppName
                "Done"
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: What error/problem etc are you having when running as  a scheduled task?  What credentials are you using?

Comment: Why can't you run this as a scheduled task? Do you get an error? Is it against some company policy? Do you not know how?

Comment: It stops here on first dependence:

`"***** Installing: " + $dependency
Add-AppxPackage -ForceApplicationShutdown $dependencies1$dependency`

It looks like it cannot run Add-AppxPackage command...

Comment: I'm using Administrator (on Raspberry PI) credential. On command line when I type .\Update.ps1 everything works ok. When I try powershell -File (or -Command) Update.ps1 it stucks... without any error od "***** Installing...." line in previous comment.