# Windows 10 IoT app update

Tags: powershell, windows-10-universal, iot

How could I update Windows 10 universal app on Windows 10 IoT running on RPi 3 using poweshell? I have an app which that is running as default app and I would like to have powershell script to update it when the new version will be avalaible. I have only found this script. The best way for me is that I will develop new app and on RPi 3 I will have timer to check for version update than the app will download it and script will update the app. I have only found [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ocarpen/2012/08/14/scripts-to-install-update-or-uninstall-a-sharepoint-2013-app-with-powershell/) and I do not know how to modify it. Could you please help me?

Comment: So if we have the powershell script to update another app, the script itself is run from an UWP app?

Comment: I am not sure but I think that the app doesn't have the permission to update itself. You have to do from the system.

Comment: UWP app runs within App Container, yet does not have the admin level privileged. Are you going to deploy your app to windows store?

Comment: At this state I am not but if there is no other possibility, I will have to.

Comment: Windows store is able to handle this?

Comment: I don't think, at least for now. Either way, I don't see an easy approach to make this happen. You link you provided is for SharedPoint app. Here is a nice tutorial for install/uninstall UWP app thru PowerShell, not sure if it's useful. http://pureinfotech.com/how-uninstall-apps-powershell-commands-windows-10/

Comment: This post might be helpful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528256/working-powershell-script-wont-run-as-scheduled-task-windows-iot-rpi-3. Not sure if it works though.

Comment: And this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552068/automatically-update-apps-inside-the-windows-10-iot-core